# Selecting top two of the combined group by linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to figure out how to pick the last two "Transactions" from my query.

My Query looks like this

```
var summary= (from tType in _context.CommandCentre.TransactionTypes
    join tSummary in _context.CommandCentre.TransSummary on tType.Id equals tSummary.TransactionType
    where tSummary.ChargeFlag.ToLower() == ChargeFlag.Overcharge.ToString().ToLower()
    group tSummary by new { tType.Name, tSummary.NumberOfTransactions, tSummary.PeriodDate }
    into gResult
    select new
    {
        Fee = gResult.Key.Name,
        TransactionCount = gResult.Key.NumberOfTransactions,
        Period = gResult.Key.PeriodDate,
        ActualAmount = gResult.Sum(x => x.ActualAmount),
    }).OrderByDescending(x=>x.Period);
```

Now if I do a `Take(2)` I get only the last two records, while I want to get the last two records for every "Fee" of my selection. Basically Two records for every "Fee" ordered by "Period" date.

not sure how to do this in a single query.

Comment: `gResult` is an `IEnumerable<T>`, you want to use `Take(2)` there

Comment: erm...where do I do a `Take(2)`. Thought need to do the "take" after Selection. Can you show with an example?

Comment: If I do a Take(2) , it gives me only the top 2. But I am trying to write the query to give me a list of top 2 for every "fee" type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
var result = summary.GroupBy(p => p.Fee)
                    .SelectMany(d => d.OrderBy(r => r.Period).Take(2))
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: Period is a `DateTime` in my case. It gives me Date related properties and methods, when I do a Period (dot).

Comment: I think he missed a ). `.SelectMany(d => d.OrderBy(r => r.Period).Take(2))`

Comment: Sorry - missed a bracket there